# Iterating over Perl hash of hashes and array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, hash-of-hashes

I'm stuck yet again and need some assistance. As usual, it's my nemesis - Hashes.
Essentially, I'm trying to write to a database, all the items of software on a z/OS mainframe. I have managed to progress to the following hash:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'Product' => {
        'Unicenter CA-Deliver Output Management' => {
            'vendorUniqueKeyRef' => 'CA',
            'swUniqueKey'        => 'RMO',
            'description'        => 'Unicenter CA-Deliver Output Management'
        },
        'Unicenter CA-JCLCheck Utility' => {
            'vendorUniqueKeyRef' => 'CA',
            'swUniqueKey'        => 'JCLCHECK',
            'description'        => 'Unicenter CA-JCLCheck Utility'
        },
        'EREP Environmental Recording Edit Print' => {
            'vendorUniqueKeyRef' => 'IBM',
            'swUniqueKey'        => 'EREP',
            'ProductVersion'     => {
                'version'       => '3',
                'swUniqueKey'   => '5658-260',
                'name'          => 'EREP Environmental Recording Edit Print',
                'versionNumber' => '03'
            },
            'description' => 'EREP Environmental Recording Edit Print'
        },
        'SYSQL' => {
            'vendorUniqueKeyRef' => 'SPLWDGRP',
            'swUniqueKey'        => 'SYSQL',
            'ProductVersion'     => {
                'ProductVersionRelease' => {
                    'releaseNumber' => '01',
                    'swUniqueKey'   => 'SYSQL-21',
                    'name'          => 'SYSQL',
                    'release'       => '1'
                },
                'version'       => '2',
                'swUniqueKey'   => 'SYSQL-2',
                'name'          => 'SYSQL',
                'versionNumber' => '02'
            },
            'description' => 'SYSQL'
        },
        '3270-PC File Transfer Program' => {
            'vendorUniqueKeyRef' => 'IBM',
            'swUniqueKey'        => '3270PCFT',
            'description'        => '3270-PC File Transfer Program'
        },
        'Tivoli OMEGAMON XE on z/OS' => {
            'vendorUniqueKeyRef' => 'IBM',
            'swUniqueKey'        => 'OMXEZO',
            'ProductVersion'     => {
                'version'       => '3',
                'swUniqueKey'   => '5698-A59',
                'name'          => 'Tivoli OMEGAMON XE on z/OS',
                'versionNumber' => '03'
            },
            'description' => 'Tivoli OMEGAMON XE on z/OS'
        },
        'Tivoli OMEGAMON XE for Messaging for z/OS' => {
            'vendorUniqueKeyRef' => 'IBM',
            'swUniqueKey'        => 'OMXEMES',
            'description'        => 'Tivoli OMEGAMON XE for Messaging for z/OS'
        },
        'DB2 Utilities Suite for z/OS' => {
            'vendorUniqueKeyRef' => 'IBM',
            'swUniqueKey'        => 'DB2UTSU',
            'ProductVersion'     => {
                'DB2 Utilities Suite for z/OS' => {
                    'swUniqueKey'   => '5655-N97',
                    'version'       => '9',
                    'versionNumber' => '09'
                },
                'DB2 Utilities Suite' => {
                    'swUniqueKey'   => '5697-E98',
                    'version'       => '7',
                    'versionNumber' => '07'
                }
            },
            'description' => 'DB2 Utilities Suite for z/OS'
        },
        'UMB' => {
            'vendorUniqueKeyRef' => 'CSC',
            'swUniqueKey'        => 'CSCUMB',
            'description'        => 'UMB'
        }
    }
};
```

Initially, all was good and I had the following:

```
my $sw = $xmldoc->{'Catalog'}->{'Products'};
my %sw = %{ $sw->{'Product'} };

foreach my $product (keys %sw) {
    print "Now processing $product\n";
    my $version;
    my $release;
    my $description        = $sw{$product}{'description'};
    my $vendorUniqueKeyRef = $sw{$product}{'vendorUniqueKeyRef'};
    my $swUniqueKey        = $sw{$product}{'swUniqueKey'};
    if ($sw{$product}{'ProductVersion'}) {
        $version = $sw{$product}{'ProductVersion'}{'version'};
        if ($sw{$product}{'ProductVersion'}{'ProductVersionRelease'}) {
            $release =
                $sw{$product}{'ProductVersion'}{'ProductVersionRelease'}
                {'release'};
        }
        else {
            $release = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        $version = 0;
        $release = 0;
    }

    my $fullVersion = "$version.$release";

    print "        ***************\n
    The product is: $product\n
    The description is: $description\n
    The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: $vendorUniqueKeyRef\n
    The ProductVersion is: $fullVersion\n
    The swUniqueKey is: $swUniqueKey\n
    ***************\n";
}
```

However, I kept getting an error about using uninitialised variables while using strict. I realised that some software had versions like ".2" instead of "2.2" and then saw that I was not properly handling the fact that some products are installed twice with different versions, something which I had stupidly not catered for.

I tried to fix that, only to find that not all version versions have a release, which I had tried to cater for, but only if they had been installed once.......

I've read up a load on getting data out of a HoH as well as an AoH, but I can't come right with this.

Essentially I'm trying to get a listing of all the software installed out of this hash into the database using DBD::ODBC (which I already have working for the rest of my program) whether it has a version, multiple versions, versions and releases, multiple versions and no releases, multiple vers...... Well you get the idea.......

I'd appreciate any help that anybody could give as weel as any advice on my current style and error checking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your post sounds like you've asked questions here before, but you are using a fresh account. What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `XML::Simple`? If so you would be far better off using an XML parser that gives you XPath-like access to your data, such as `XML::LibXML` or `XML::Twig`.

As it stands you would be better off maintaining scalar variables to point at each step inside the hash structure. That would avoid multiple keys to access an element as well as using the same hash access repeatedly. You *shouldn't* copy to another hash as you do in `my %sw = %{ $sw->{'Product'} }` because there is no point in copying all the hash keys and values. I have used `my $products = $sw->{Product}` in the code below, and then `my $product = $products->{$prodname}` and `my $pv = $product->{ProductVersion}`.

You would also benefit by using hash slices, and the code sould be clearer if you dropped the quotes from around the hash keys (this works only if the keys are alphanumeric). I pull out the first three product parameters in one line using a slice.

Here is a rewrite of the piece of code you showed us. The biggest change is that I have checked to see whether there is a `ProductVersion/version` element. If so then I combine `version` and `ProductVersionRelease/release` from beneath `ProductVersion`. Otherwise I do the same beneath *all* `ProductVersion/*` elements. The `//` defined-or is useful to default these values to zero if they are not present.

I hope this is closer to what you wanted.

```
my $products = $sw->{Product};

foreach my $prodname (keys %$products) {

    print "\n\nNow processing $prodname\n";

    my $product = $products->{$prodname};

    my ($description, $vendorUniqueKeyRef, $swUniqueKey) =
            @$product{qw/ description vendorUniqueKeyRef swUniqueKey /};

    my @versions;
    if (my $pv = $product->{ProductVersion}) {
        for my $ver (exists $pv->{version} ? $pv : values %$pv) {
          push @versions, sprintf "%d.%d",
              $ver->{version} // 0,
              $ver->{ProductVersionRelease}{release} // 0;
        }
    } 

    print "***************\n";
    print "The product is: $prodname\n";
    print "The description is: $description\n";
    print "The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: $vendorUniqueKeyRef\n";
    print "The ProductVersion is: $_\n" for @versions;
    print "The swUniqueKey is: $swUniqueKey\n";
    print "***************\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Now processing DB2 Utilities Suite for z/OS
***************
The product is: DB2 Utilities Suite for z/OS
The description is: DB2 Utilities Suite for z/OS
The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: IBM
The ProductVersion is: 9.0
The ProductVersion is: 7.0
The swUniqueKey is: DB2UTSU
***************

Now processing UMB
***************
The product is: UMB
The description is: UMB
The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: CSC
The swUniqueKey is: CSCUMB
***************

Now processing EREP Environmental Recording Edit Print
***************
The product is: EREP Environmental Recording Edit Print
The description is: EREP Environmental Recording Edit Print
The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: IBM
The ProductVersion is: 3.0
The swUniqueKey is: EREP
***************

Now processing Unicenter CA-JCLCheck Utility
***************
The product is: Unicenter CA-JCLCheck Utility
The description is: Unicenter CA-JCLCheck Utility
The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: CA
The swUniqueKey is: JCLCHECK
***************

Now processing Unicenter CA-Deliver Output Management
***************
The product is: Unicenter CA-Deliver Output Management
The description is: Unicenter CA-Deliver Output Management
The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: CA
The swUniqueKey is: RMO
***************

Now processing 3270-PC File Transfer Program
***************
The product is: 3270-PC File Transfer Program
The description is: 3270-PC File Transfer Program
The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: IBM
The swUniqueKey is: 3270PCFT
***************

Now processing SYSQL
***************
The product is: SYSQL
The description is: SYSQL
The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: SPLWDGRP
The ProductVersion is: 2.1
The swUniqueKey is: SYSQL
***************

Now processing Tivoli OMEGAMON XE for Messaging for z/OS
***************
The product is: Tivoli OMEGAMON XE for Messaging for z/OS
The description is: Tivoli OMEGAMON XE for Messaging for z/OS
The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: IBM
The swUniqueKey is: OMXEMES
***************

Now processing Tivoli OMEGAMON XE on z/OS
***************
The product is: Tivoli OMEGAMON XE on z/OS
The description is: Tivoli OMEGAMON XE on z/OS
The vendorUniqueKeyRef is: IBM
The ProductVersion is: 3.0
The swUniqueKey is: OMXEZO
***************
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! You're not the first person to suggest XML::LibXML and I tried to install it. I'm using ActiveState Perl and ppm downloads an old version. I tried compiling the source on Win 64bit but got errors and haven't had the time to take it further.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your product `DB2 Utilities Suite for z/OS`. In the `ProductVersion` key there are two other product names. All the others do not have that.

```
'DB2 Utilities Suite for z/OS' => {
  'vendorUniqueKeyRef' => 'IBM',
  'swUniqueKey' => 'DB2UTSU',
  'ProductVersion' => {
    'DB2 Utilities Suite for z/OS' => {
      'swUniqueKey' => '5655-N97',
      'version' => '9',
      'versionNumber' => '09'
    },
    'DB2 Utilities Suite' => {
      'swUniqueKey' => '5697-E98',
      'version' => '7',
      'versionNumber' => '07'
    }
  },
  'description' => 'DB2 Utilities Suite for z/OS'
},
```

You need to cater for that. Do you have an XML schema for your XML data?